# Name of the fabric towels are made from - flannel or terry cloth?

Tags: word-usage

Background: I was asked to apply "hot flannel towel" by my optician; to alleviate a mild eye lid inflammation, not important. My question is what she meant by the "**flannel towel**".

**Terry cloth** (or terrycloth) - this is the fabric towels are normally made of. As Wikipedia puts it: *fabric with loops that can absorb large amounts of water*. It's surface is coarse, it's made for rubbing. In my language we use ***froté***, from French ***frotté***, meaning *rubbing*.

**Flannel** - this is the fabric shirts can be made; and also blankets and bed sheets. NOT towels. It's soft and smooth and not a great water absorbent.

Thinking that "flannel towel" would mean a towel made of flannel, that is a special type of a towel, I started to search on Amazon. But to my surprise, all the results terry towels labelled as flannel towels.

Flannel even seems to be even used as a synonym to towel.

Is it something historic? Like that towels used to be made flannel before terry cloth was invented? Please, can someone shed some light on this?

And back to my optician advice, should I keep searching for a towel specifically made of flannel?

**UPDATE:**
The optician is British English.

**UPDATE 2019-09-06:**
So I simply emailed the optician. Their answer was:  *A small face cloth will help or any small terrycloth towel also.*

Comment: Searching for a fabric is probably less important than immediate treatment with some kind of hot/wet towel, although I doubt you are supposed to rub the eye. Use a small towel that is soft and will shape itself to the contours of your face. A face cloth is sometimes called a **flannel**.

Comment: To me a "flannel" towel had a tighter, shorter nap than a "terry" towel.

Comment: towels are made from cotton. Flannel cloth is pressed.

Comment: Go on, let us into your secret. What was the nationality of the optician?

Comment: I call them 'face flannels', which is probably because I am a Brit. A face flannel is often, but not always, made of the same material as a towel - absorbent terrycloth.Flannel (colloquially) refers to the usage of the piece of cloth, not its composition.(+1).

Comment: @Lambie — not when the word towel was first coined. Then they were made of linen. And tea towels (probably British English) are often still made of (Irish) linen. But cotton makes more absorbent towel.

Comment: To this Brit, a flannel is simply a towel the size of a handkerchief. If your optician is British, that is undoubtedly what she meant.

Comment: Are you asking if towels are *never* made of flannel but *always* made of terrycloth (or some other material that would make flannel an error)? Has there never in history been a single towel made of flannel? (I'm also not sure what this has to do with English as opposed to facts, historical or otherwise.)

Comment: @David  I didn't know that that face flannel was a face cloth in the UK. Yes, towels were made of linen, as are many dish towels, as we say in the US.

Comment: As the comments indicate, locale is very important when asking about terminology. Please [edit] the question to indicate which dialect your optician speaks.

Comment: Thank you all! I am bit wiser now though still not completely sure. The best think would be probably to simply ask the optician ;) I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if she meant flannel/towel. As in either/or. Which would make more sense.

In the UK, a flannel or face flannel is a small square of terry-cloth or towelling used for washing the face or body.

Towelling is the material that towels are made from.

Terry-cloth fabric is used for flannels, or nappies (traditional square cloth diapers). Terry cloth is probably less-known now, and more often called ‘towelling’. My mother used to refer to ‘terry nappies’, I remember.

‘Flannel’, additionally is a soft usually wool or worsted dense fabric used for trousers suits or coats.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/towelling

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flannel

Answer (score 0):

Towels are indeed made of terry (or terrycloth), and flannel is everywhere a woven cloth made of wool. But adding to the confusion, the word “flannel” is indeed sometimes used in the U.K. to refer to what the US calls a “washcloth;” see sense 4 here:

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/flannel

So I am pretty positive your doctor just meant a plain old ordinary washcloth.

Comment: Except that won't help much if he is in Britain, and two of his other questions specified British English.

Answer (score -1):

*Terry*, despite its pedigree (see the comment by @HotLicks) is almost unknown in Britain. So I cannot comment on that as an answer.

Flannel has many meanings, and in Britain, most notably, *flannel* is a fabric used for trousers.

*A Flannel* is also a face cloth in Britains. So, without reaching for my OED, I’d avoid that one.

It may seem lame, but personally I would say towels are made of **towelling**. And the [Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/towelling) lends me some support in this respect:

> **towelling**
>
> a soft, thick cloth used especially for making towels or clothing:

And consulting my OED, I discover the word *towelling* was first used in *1585*.

I don’t think you’ll do any better in English. As we say, *“The French have a word for it”.*

Comment: Despite the negative response to my answer, I refuse to throw in the towel!

Comment: "A Flannel is also a face cloth in Britains. So, without reaching for my OED, I’d avoid that one." - Why are you avoiding it? That's literally the answer the OP needs. It's an X-Y problem.

Comment: @AndyT— Something of a wet blanket ;-) ?

Comment: _"A Flannel is also a face cloth in Britains. So, without reaching for my OED, I’d avoid that one._" - Why are you avoiding it? Yeah, that's literary the right answer as best I can judge.

Comment: @FlaviusIulianus — Your optician may have suggested that you used the material that a face cloth or flannel is made of, but your question was what was the name of the *material*, not what was the name of the *object*. (I imagine also that the material rather than the object was specified so that you could cut up the object into strips and sterilize it in boiling water, rather than using a non-sterile face cloth.)